# Dealing with auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, screen, nslayoutconstraint

I wasted few hours on constraints and I am still having issue.In
`iPhone 6` screen, it is working perfectly but it is not working in iPhone 5/4. I set all views (image is background) to have fix W/H and hit auto add missing constraints.

As you can see on iPhone 5 its always pin to right, sometime to left. I Can't add anything its comes with error.

Any help? or some damn good tutorial for this :)

[image]

Comment: Hard to say with the information you given, but seems like you have constraints on the left side enforcing a margin, which makes it seem like the content is pinned to the right

Answer (score 1):

I made an example just for one row of your buttons, so they can be reused for other UI elements.

I put these constraints onto my buttons:

LEFT BUTTON:

- left leading constraint
- top leading constraint
- height constraint

RIGHT BUTTON

- right trailing constraint
- top leading constraint
- height constraint

And constraints related to both buttons:
(you need to select both buttons to be able to apply relation constraints)

- spacing constraint between buttons
- equal width of these buttons

In **Interface Builder** it looks like this:

[image]

And these layout is **universal**, so I chose some device sizes to present:

**iPhone 5**
[image]

**iPhone 6**
[image]

**iPhone 6 Plus**
[image]

... etc.